# want to send command and get an image from camera

Tags: python, microcontroller, micropython

Hey guys I need some help.
I am using an Industrial camera for clicking an image. First I use Hyper Terminal to communicate with camera which gave the feedbacks and images.

Now I want to try using my own code to connect and get feedbacks and Image using python.

I successfully connected the camera and got feedbacks from it but when i pass any command to it then it is not responding over command. when I send GI0000 command then the camera sends the image.

Does anyone had any idea how can I send data to camera or how hyperterminal  sends data (basically in which form).

The given code is only of client side because we can't change any thing in camera and the data and image will be send of one reading only.
I just want help in sending data to camera which is "GI0000" and "TR".
And if any one have any kind of suggestion then sincerely welcome.

when I remove that TR command then I am getting continuously getting data but not image.
Tr = Trigger the camera.
GI0000 = Get the latest image.

## only client side code

```
Import socket

host = '169.254.0.1'
port = 23
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))

s.send(bytes("TR","utf-8"))
with open('receive_file','ab') as f:
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        f.write(data)
        s.send(bytes("GI0000","utf-8"))
        with open('got.bmp','wb') as ff:
            while True:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    ff.write(data)
            ff.close()
f.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Interesting, perhaps the driver has some documentation on the commands?

Comment: Try to append some newline code at the end of each command. It might be `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`, depending on what you send with Hyper Terminal and what the camera expects. You could use Wireshark (the network sniffer) to watch what is send between your PC and the camera.

Comment: thank you IronMan and the busybee. Once i get get solution i'll post it.

Comment: Hey Guys I got The Solution.                                                                          
  with open('Receive_image.bmp', 'wb') as ff:
            print("file made")
            s.settimeout(1)
            while True:
                try:
                    data = bytes(s.recv(1024))
                except socket.timeout:
                    ff.close()
                    break
                print(data)
                if data:
                    ff.write(data)
        print("Data Received")            Thank You For Your Help